# Install Microsoft SQL Server Native Client (bcp.exe) 2017

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how to install the `bcp.exe` in SQL 2017? If in MSSQL 2012 was easy to find during to install, in MSSQL 2017 Developer Edition apparently I cannot find it. Thanks!

**SQL 2012**

[image]

Comment: "The bcp 13.0 client is installed when you install Microsoft SQL Server 2017 tools" - Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#remarks

Comment: `bcp` is not the native client but the command line bulk copy utility. The native client is the OLE DB/ODBC driver for SQL connectivity from programs.

Comment: Ok. But i need to use the `bcp.exe` application. Where can I find it?

Comment: Standalone, it's part of the [SQL Server 2016 feature pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) (`ENU\<platform>\MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi`). AFAICT there is no newer version for 2017; the 2016 version is fully compatible. I don't know what checkbox in the main SQL Server setup you have to tick for it, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server client tools are being decoupled from the server components in later SQL versions. This includes SSMS as well as command-line utilities. Below are some links.

- [Command-line utilities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591)
- [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)
- [SQL Operations Studio (open-source cross-platform GUI, preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download)
- [mssql-scripter (open-source, cross-platform command-line)](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-scripter)